# Wrong data being highlighted in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet, formula, conditional-formatting

I am using the formula =AND($M1="Y",$N1>$E1) in conditional formatting to highlight text red when the date in column N is later than the date in column E, and the entry in column M is 'Y'.

However, the formula is also highlighting all the text when there is no entry in column E. Is there anything I can add to the formula to alter that, as i want the text to remain normal if either E or N aren't filled.

I can try writing a new rule making all the text of an entry normal if column E is empty, and set it to override the rule above, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

Adding more conditions in the `AND()`?

```
=AND($M1="Y",$N1>$E1, $N1<>"", $E1<>"")
```

`<>` is the opposite of `=` and `""` means blank.

Comment: @pnuts True, now that you mention it; if $N1 is empty, $N1>$E1 will not be satisfied anyway. So, it could indeed be shortened to `=AND($M1="Y",$N1>$E1, $E1<>"")`